# Как сериализовать unmodifiableMap?

Tags: jaxb, serialize, java

Как сериализовать unmodifiableMap?

Есть класс:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "language")
public class Language {

    @XmlElement(required = true, name = "texts")
    private Map<String, String> texts;

    private Language(LanguageName langName) {
        this.langName = langName;

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        // ...
        // init map
        // ...

        this.texts = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

Но при десериализации texts становится обычным мапом, не факт, что HashMap. Нужно, чтобы после десериализации мапа была неизменяема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать собственный адаптер (см. [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html)).